# Other than X Y coordinates ,how can I view other values/information present in an imported shapefile

Tags: netlogo, shapefile

I loaded a shapefile into NetLogo.
called "locations".
I can be able to view the XY coordinates in the command center. However, I want to view the OBJECTID (present in the shapefile) of each coordinate.I need this information for reference purposes.
What can I do to be able to view the OBJECTID of each line feature in the shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this example setup, where "Sector_Boundary.shp" is a shapefile with 10 subunits:

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ example-gis-data ]

to setup
  ca
  set example-gis-data gis:load-dataset "Sector_Boundary.shp"
  gis:set-drawing-color white
  gis:draw example-gis-data 1
  reset-ticks  
end
```

If you literally just need to output the object ids, you could pull the list of features using `gis:feature-list-of` and then use `gis:property-value` to pull the "OBJECTID" for each one:

```
to view-info
  let list-of-features gis:feature-list-of example-gis-data
  let list-of-ids map [ i -> gis:property-value i "OBJECTID" ] list-of-features
  print list-of-ids
end
```

You can of course do the same thing for different property names as needed, and output other reference info as needed. For example, if your locations shapefile had a NAME field as my "Sector_Boundary.shp" does, you could do something like:

```
to view-info
  let list-of-features gis:feature-list-of example-gis-data
  let list-of-ids map [ i -> gis:property-value i "OBJECTID" ] list-of-features
  let list-of-names map [ i -> gis:property-value i "NAME" ] list-of-features
  ( foreach list-of-names list-of-ids [
    [ name id ] ->
    print ( word "Name: " name ", Object id: " id )
  ])  
end
```

to view the name associated with each object id.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Luke. Your instructions were very easy to follow.

Comment: @chief - No problem! If that answer resolves your issue, please click the checkmark beside it to mark your question as closed.